# How to send Multiple message to JMS Endpoint in Mule

Tags: mule, mule-component, mule-connector

In Mule, I have a requirement to split the request XML data and construct Multiple mule messages and post them to a JMS queue.

I have managed to split the message and have a list of Mule Message in my Java component.
My question is, how do I pass the list of mule message to a JMS endpoint as individual message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using a `foreach` component. You can change the collection in case you save it to a flowVar.

```xml
<foreach doc:name="For Each" collection="#[payload]">
    <jms:outbound-endpoint doc:name="JMS" connector-ref="JMS" queue="myQueue"/>
</foreach>
```